# What makes electric field zero in a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, superconductivity, conductors, electromagnetic-induction

Take a ideal inductor (superconductor). Change in magnetic field produces electric field. But in a ideal inductor electric field inside is zero.
What makes the electric field zero in a ideal inductor when it
is connected to a circuit.

Another question is why is electric field inside a ideal conducting wire zero when it is connected in a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

In the steady state condition, there is no electric field inside a perfect conductor because the electrons have moved to cancel out any electric field.  That is because electrons will move whenever there *is* an electric field.

However, while the electric field inside a conductor is changing, there is a lag between the imposition of the new field and the rearrangement of the electrons.  Primarily this is due to inductance.  As a result, there *is* an electric field inside a conductor while the imposed electric field is changing and, in the case where the imposed field is changed in a single abrupt step, during the brief time while the electron distribution is changing to its new steady-state condition.

Comment: Why infinite current not possible in a ideal circuit.

Comment: Think about what induction means and how it works in a wire loop.

Comment: What is the problem with infinite current in a circuit

Comment: "Infinite" is always a problem in physics, regardless of the context.

Comment: Imagine starting with zero current, then rising to a very large (not even infinite) current, in a short length of time.  A circuit is at least one loop, so there will be induction.

Answer (score 0):

Resistance, R, is defined as voltage drop/current.  If R is zero, then the voltage drop and the E field must be zero. Zero resistance does not imply that the current is infinite.  If a superconductor is part of a circuit with other elements which do have resistance, then the other elements determine the current. (Consider a superconducting long distance power line.) In most applications the superconductor is the circuit (such as a large electromagnet.) Then the problem becomes: How do you introduce a current? (Always a limited process).